# Criar múltiplas variáveis PHP em uma mesma função

Tags: php

Preciso de uma função bem simples, mas não consegui achar nada relacionado nas minhas pesquisas.

Preciso de uma função onde eu possa inserir itens, e depois imprimir estes itens em outra página.

Ex:

```
    function funcaoExibe() {
 $var = 'none1';
 $var = 'email2';
 $var = 'telefone3';
    echo $var;
}
```

Criada a função, preciso exibir todos os valores das variáveis inseridas dentro da função, algo assim:

```
   <?= funcaoExibe(); ?>

No resultado aparece somente:

telefone3
```

Preciso que seja exibido os 3, um em cada linha.

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer?

Comment: coloca o echo dentro da função

Comment: É que a função vai ficar em uma página, e o resultado em outra. Não vai ficar tudo no mesmo arquivo PHP.

Comment: Como você disse acima, o processamento vai ficar em um arquivo e o resultado em outro. Você pode retornar na função um html e exibir na página desejada.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, o problema é que naõ sei como devo criar essa função.

Comment: vc está sobrescrevendo a variável `$var`. Não deu pra entender mto bem o que vc quer. A função deveria receber 3 argumentos e imprimir e não ter os valores definidos dentro dela.

Comment: Você poderia trabalhar com get e set neste caso, set coloca as informações e get pega as informações

Answer (score 1):

Você pode montar o html em um arquivo php e exibir em outro dessa forma.

//arquivo_funcao.php

```
    <?php
       function ProcessarInformacao($nome, $email, $telefone) {
          $html  = "<div>";
          $html .= "<p>Nome: ".$nome."</p>";
          $html .= "<p>Email: ".$email."</p>";
          $html .= "<p>Telefone: ".$telefone."</p>";
          $html  = "</div>";

          return $html;
       }
    ?>
```

//exibir_resultado.php

```
echo ProcessarInformacao('Nome Teste', 'teste@teste.com.br', '(17) 3030-4040');
```

Comment: Não seria isso, as variáveis nome, email, telefone não existe, usei apenas como exemplo. É que eu preciso carregar arquivos JS em uma página específica, então irei colocar dentro da função qual JS deve ser carregado na página, e onde exibe o resultado, vai inserir as linhas com a URL do JS.

Comment: Releia sua pergunta e formule ela corretamente, pois está complicado de entender o que você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com que a função retorne um vetor (array)
No arquivo a.php você insere as informações:

***a.php***

```
<?php
function funcaoExibe( $nome, $email, $telefone ) {
  $retorno = array(
    'nome'  => $nome,
    'email' => $email,
    'fone'  => $telefone
  );    
return $retorno;    
} 
?>
```

Aí você escolhe o que quer exibir

```
<?php
  $var = funcaoExibe('Carlos', 'carlos@email.com', '(12)3454-6555');
  echo  $var['nome']."<br>" ;
  echo  $var['email']."<br>" ;
  echo  $var['fone']."<br>" ;
?>
```